# JodaTime period returns unexpected results

Tags: android, date, datetime, jodatime

I am trying to calculate the difference between any two given times in an android app.  To accomplish this task I was using JodaTime and the Period class along with Period's getYears(), getDays(), getHours(), getMinutes(), and getSeconds() methods.  However, I realized that it is giving what seems the be the absolute difference between each element of the date.  For example, calling my function on the dates `2017-01-29 00:00:00 (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)` and `2018-01-28 00:00:00` will return:

```
0 years
2 days
0 hours
0 minutes
0 seconds
```

when it should return `364 days` along with zeros in every other section.  Of course, it is an android app so I am not printing them, I am handling the display separately.  I was able to do this on my computer using LocalDateTime and Duration.between, but I cannot use these classes here.  I am looking for either a fix for my current method (which is below) or suggestions for a completely new approach.  Thank you in advance.
My current function:

```
public int[] getDifference(DateTime start, DateTime end){
    Period p = new Period(start, end);
    int[] differences = new int[5];
    differences[0] = p.getYears();
    differences[1] = p.getDays();
    differences[2] = p.getHours();
    differences[3] = p.getMinutes();
    differences[4] = p.getSeconds();
    return differences;
}
```

Comment: Duration is what you want - why can't you use it?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you expect 364 days? Read the [class doc for `Period`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html).

> public int getDays()
>
> Gets the days field part of the period.

The “field part” is the key here. A `Period` is a number of years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds. For example, a year and a half would have two parts, a *years* part of 1 and a *months* part of 6.

Your output skipped over the *months* part and the *weeks* part.

```
DateTime start = new DateTime ( 2017 , 1 , 29 , 0 , 0 , DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime stop = new DateTime ( 2018 , 1 , 28 , 0 , 0 , DateTimeZone.UTC );
Period p = new Period ( start , stop );
int[] differences = new int[ 7 ];
differences[ 0 ] = p.getYears ();
differences[ 1 ] = p.getMonths ();
differences[ 2 ] = p.getWeeks ();
differences[ 3 ] = p.getDays ();
differences[ 4 ] = p.getHours ();
differences[ 5 ] = p.getMinutes ();
differences[ 6 ] = p.getSeconds ();
System.out.println ( "differences: " + Arrays.toString ( differences ) );
```

When run, we see eleven months, four weeks, and two days. Running Joda-Time 2.8.2 in Java 8 Update 121 on macOS El Capitan.

> differences: [0, 11, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0]

You might think of calling `toStandardDays`. But doing so results in an exception (`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`) saying: “Cannot convert to Days as this period contains months and months vary in length”.

## java.time

FYI: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

In java.time, a span of time unattached to the timeline is represented as either years-month-days in `java.time.Period` or hours-minutes-seconds-nanoseconds in `java.time.Duration`.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

The java.time classes eschew constructors, using factory methods instead.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of ( 2017 , 1 , 29 );
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of ( 2018 , 1 , 28 );
Period period = Period.between ( start , stop );
System.out.println ( "period.toString(): " + period );
```

The `toString` generates a piece of text in [standard ISO 8601 format for durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). We see here eleven months and thirty days. Obviously Joda-Time and java.time count differently. Here we see different results. Joda-Time counts weeks while java.time does not.

> period.toString(): P11M30D

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

`Period p = new Period(start, end);`

with

`Period p = new Period(start, end, PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime());`

Answer (score 0):

You should also set the appropriate period type because you want a specific normalization to years, days, hours, minutes and seconds only, see also javadoc.

```
LocalDateTime start = new LocalDateTime(2017, 1, 29, 0, 0);
LocalDateTime end = new LocalDateTime(2018, 1, 28, 0, 0);
Period p = new Period(start, end, PeriodType.yearDayTime().withMillisRemoved());
System.out.println(p); // P364D (what you expected)
```

This example would also work with the type `DateTime` for start and end.

Please note that this code example (as the class `Period` of Joda-Time itself) cannot be fully migrated to new `java.time`-API contained in Java-8 because latter API cannot handle durations with date AND time components. It can also not specify the period type i.e. cannot control the normalization as `PeriodType` does.